# Interval arg in postgres query executed via Golang SQLX

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I have the following SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO scheduled_event_log ("key")
SELECT :key WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT AGE(now() at time zone 'utc', timestamp_utc)
FROM scheduled_event_log
WHERE "key" = :key
    AND age(now() at time zone 'utc', timestamp_utc) < :interval limit 1 );
```

`:interval` is the Postgres interval type.  I prepare this as a named statement using sqlx but passing args to `Exec(..)` where `:interval` is a Golang `time.Duration` causes a panic.

How should an interval be specified as an argument in this way?

Comment: What does the panic say?

Comment: have you tried $1, $2, ...?

Comment: `Interval` a bad name for a variable  (or parameter), since  it is the name for a data type. And the `LIMIT 1` makes no sense inside an `EXISTS` subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Unless anything has changed since 2013 this is a *WontFix* https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4954 with the suggested solution being to implement `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer`

However, for my use case I have found that simply making the argument a `string` and calling `time.Duration.String()` works. I'm working with seconds only and have only tested in this range so YMMV.